# WinAPI: Editboxes corner is not rendered correctly inside a rectangle

Tags: winapi, rendering

When trying to rerender a window with a textbox the corner of the textbox is not rendered correctly.
It's just white, there is no corner. Directly after creating the textbox, everything is OK. After rerendering using `InvalidateRect(NULL, NULL, true);`, the box is away and there is only the text in it until I move the mouse over it.

The edit is created using CreateWindowEx with the parameters `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` and `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL`

**Update:** Just found out that the problem is away when rendering outside of a rectangle.

**Example**: When loading the WinAPI example project which ships with Mono-D ([winsamp.d](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/samples/winsamp.d)) and adding the following code to WM_PAINT: `RoundRect(dc, 0, 0, 300, 300, 1, 1);` and the following code to a button click handler (the one with IDC_BTNCLICK)

```
                try
                {
                    HMENU h = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "edit".toUTF16z, "".toUTF16z, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 100, 100, 100, 100, hWnd, cast(HMENU)100, GetModuleHandleA(null), null);
                    HFONT font = CreateFontW(15, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, CP_UTF8, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, ("Tahoma").toUTF16z);
                    SendMessageA(h, WM_SETFONT, cast(int)font, 0);
                    InvalidateRect(null, null, true);
                }
                catch(Throwable e) {}
```

the problem occurs.

Comment: Does your parent window contain the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag?

Comment: No, it does not. When adding it, nothing happens.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your question complete, answerable, and more valuable to future visitors.

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: I think I had similar problem, perhaps [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378938/edit-control-not-repainted-entirely-with-chosen-brush) can help you? *Please go through my question to make sure I understood your post correct. Look at the pictures and see if that is the problem you get. Thank you.*

Comment: I tried calling `RedrawWindow(null, null, null, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE);` as you did but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "rerender a window"?

Comment: Calling `InvalidateRect(null, null, true);`

Comment: I believe this is a theming issue where the underlying parent window colour is being clipped out by the child's rect. Does your parent have `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` applied?

Comment: What is the rationale for using the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window style for your Edit control? And where is the code that creates the Edit control's parent window? Don't ignore the documentation for [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx) either. The `hWnd` parameter has the following advice: *"Setting this parameter to `NULL` is not recommended."*

Comment: IInspectable is right: When hWnd is set, the error doesn't occur. Thank you very much for your help!